# bit.trip runner dx9 failed to create full screen device

Tags: technical-issues, directx-9, bit-trip-runner

When i try to run bit.trip runner I get this error: "dx9 failed to create full screen device" already tried changing settings in game.cfg yet no matter what settings i use i get the same error :/ Anyone know how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found out that my GPU is too old for this game (it only support OpenGL 1.4 :/ ) It`s still possible to play this game with [swift shader 3](http://www.alltypehacks.net/2014/01/swiftshader-30-play-hd-games-in-slow.html) though it maybe slower than it should be, its playable.